# jQuery DateTimePicker for v1.6.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know a DateTimePicker that works with jQuery v1.6.2?

I can't upgrade the jQuery, so I am condemned to use v1.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this [Addon](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) works with jQuery 1.6+.
It extends the jQuery-UI DatePicker.

It works like this: `$('#textBox').datetimepicker();`