# Adding On() and Off() methods in jQuery 1.4

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add the On() and Off() methods to jQuery 1.4.3 version without causing any side effects. The problem is we like to use a library but that depends on a newer version of jQuery (1.7.2+). We tried using migrate but its bombing in other areas.

I am looking for a stop gap way to fix it before we upgrade.

Specifically i am trying to port [jquery.datetimepicker plugin](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) to jquery 1.4 similar to [jQuery DateTimePicker for v1.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647745/jquery-datetimepicker-for-v1-6-2) - I tried replacing the on with live and off with die but doesn't work.

Any ideas help.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no `on` and `off` methods in ancient versions of jQuery! **Upgrade!**

Comment: @adeneo I believe OP is aware of that, hence the question :-)

Comment: :) We are stuck in ancient times for a large application and its hard to upgrade without doing full regression.

Comment: jQuery is already in version 1.11.0 or 2.1.0, you should upgrade!

Comment: @PaulRoub - the answer is still to upgrade.

Comment: You can find the source [here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=on), but just pasting it in probably won't work as the entire library is changed, you'd have to write custom methods that map back to `live` etc

Comment: I am looking for a stop gap way to fix it before we upgrade.

Comment: I'm looking to get colors on my B/W TV.

Comment: You'll find yourself locked in a never-ending sequence of problems trying to find shims to fit modern methods into an ancient library (and asking questions here, the comments to which will always be "upgrade!") until you finally upgrade. So, skip the pain and just upgrade.

Comment: Agree ! I am pro for upgrade always, its just that I am stuck with supporting ancient application while creating a new breed of applications confirming to latest ones.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `on()` in that ancient version is the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function. By analogy, `off()`'s counterpart is [die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/).

That's probably as close as you can get to bridging that gap.

Comment: Doesn't work but thanks. I guess no other way but upgrade.I will answer my own question. Thanks

Comment: Ok specifically i am trying to port jquery.datetimepicker plugin to jquery 1.4 similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647745/jquery-datetimepicker-for-v1-6-2 - I tried replacing the on with live and off with die but doesn't work.

Comment: They do/can have different parameters, but it shouldn't be too hard to make a rewriter function, right?

Comment: You are right but straight replacing doesn't work - I will probably spend sometime tonight to port it and publish it.